# is there a hardforked version of ubuntu ethereum ppa package?

Tags: hardforks, ubuntu, ppa, repositories

The ubuntu ppa still contains ETH classic.  Is there a ppa for the hard-forked version of Ethereum?

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

- The **ethereum-dev** ppa currently has `geth` **v1.5.0-unstable**
- The **ethereum** ppa currently has `geth` **1.4.10-stable**
- Remove / purge your **ethereum-dev** ppa to use the non-dev **v1.5.0-unstable** version.

---

### Details

From http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/installing-binaries/linux-ubuntu-ppa.html:

> ### Installing the “eth” command-line tool
>
> WARNING: The ethereum-qt PPA will upgrade your system-wide Qt5 installation, from 5.2 on Trusty and 5.3 on Utopic, to 5.5.
>
> For the latest stable version:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum-qt
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install cpp-ethereum
> ```
>
> If you want to use the cutting edge developer version:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum-qt
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum-dev
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install cpp-ethereum
> ```

If you have added the **ethereum-dev** ppa repository, you will currently have `geth` **v1.5.0-unstable** installed.

If you have only added the non-dev **ethereum** ppa repository, you will currently have `geth` **1.4.10** installed.

```
user@Kumquat:~$ dpkg -l ethereum
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                         Version             Architecture        Description
+++-============================-===================-===================-=============================================================
ii  ethereum                     1.4.10+83trusty-0ub amd64               Meta-package to install geth (CLI) and other tools
```

---

To remove **ethereum-dev** ppa:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ sudo apt-add-repository remove ethereum-dev
...
user@Kumquat:~$ sudo apt-get update
...
user@Kumquat:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade ethereum
...
user@Kumquat:~$ geth version
Geth
Version: 1.4.10-stable
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.5.1
OS: linux
...
user@Kumquat:~$ geth help | grep dao
  --support-dao-fork   Updates the chain rules to support the DAO hard-fork
  --oppose-dao-fork    Updates the chain rules to oppose the DAO hard-fork
```

---

A **safer** way to remove your ppas would be to use the `ppa-purge` tool. From [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed):

> Use the --remove flag, similar to how the PPA was added:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa
> ```
>
> As a safer alternative, you can install ppa-purge:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
> ```
>
> And then remove the PPA, downgrading gracefully packages it provided to packages provided by official repositories:
>
> ```
> sudo ppa-purge ppa_name
> ```
>
> Anyway, this won't uninstall packages that were on the PPA but not on tha official repositories. If you want to remove them, you should tell it to apt:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get purge package_name
> ```
>
> You can also remove PPAs by deleting the .list files from /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory.
>
> Last but not least, you can also disable or remove PPAs from the "Software Sources" section in Ubuntu Settings with a few clicks of your mouse (no terminal needed).

Comment: Okay, this is what I was looking for. I've deleted my answer as this one is clearly the right one :)